# Trying to get the src link from an image in selenium-webdriver in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get the source link of an img element in node.

I'm currently using this but it's returning a promise object...

```
var element = driver.findElement(By.className('text-body'))
let url = element.getAttribute('src')
console.log(url)
```

Result:
`[object Promise]`

I can't use the ID of the element as it changes every time a new page is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, whenever you see `[object Promise]` that means the function is returning a Promise. To wait for the Promise to complete, use `await` within an `async function` or add a callback:

```
async function getImageUrl(element) {
  const url = await element.getAttribute('src');
  console.log(url);
  return url;
}

// or...
element.getAttribute('src').then(url => console.log(url));
```